# Terraform aws_s3_object with nested for loops

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, terraform, nested-loops

I have a tf code to create folders via aws_s3_object resource and am trying to modify the current code:

```
variable "s3_bucket_folders" {
type = set(string)
default = []
}


resource "aws_s3_object" "folders" {
for_each = var.s3_bucket_folders
bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
acl = "private"
key = each.key
}
```

I also want the bucket to be using a for_each so that in every bucket I specify the folders mentioned should be created. I tried using a map with dynamic but am running into errors, can anyone specify the best solution for this

Trying to find the best possible solution to create all these folders withing buckets from one resource block

Answer (score 1):

Transform your list to a set for the foreach to iterate over

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "folders" {
    for_each = toset(var.s3_bucket_folders)
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
    acl = "private"
    key = each.key
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks but I am already doing that in the variable block. What I want is to create folder1, folder2, folder3 in bucket1 and folder1, folder2, folder3, folder4 in bucket2 from the 
 same resource block

Comment: Sorry totally missed that. So you have defined your list of folders  where are you defining your list of buckets.

Answer (score -1):

```html
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "folders" {
    count   = "${length(var.s3_bucket_folders)}"
    bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.b.id}"
    acl    = "private"
    key    = "${var.s3_bucket_folders[count.index]}/"
    source = "/dev/null"
}
```

use count instead of for_each

Comment: Thanks for that but using a count will destroy the resource when altering the list. Is there a way you can di this with for each?